# What is a word for the following manner?

Tags: meaning-in-context

What do you call someone who excessively swears?

Comment: Foul-mouthed (person). Foul-tongued.

Comment: From the 1950s I can remember *blackguard* (or *blaggard*) being used in that sense. Though the OED does not record it among the many other senses in which  *blackguard* has been employed across the centuries.

Comment: Do you mean the medical condition given in Marshall Jon Mark Perry's answer, or just a foul-mouthed person?  Please clarify.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be considered to be a medical condition, known as [Coprolalia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coprolalia), and often mistook as [Tourette Syndrome](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tourette_syndrome).